# Button that can read that you watched the whole video or password protected page?

Tags: javascript, passwords, password-protection

Okay so I am working on a site much like Lawline.com where I have to come up with a way that a user must watch the video and then a button or something pops up and they can get their "credit" however I am not quite sure how I am going to code that (If anyone has any ideas javascript since I know how to script that language that'd be super).

```
<button type="button" onclick="vid_play_pause()">Play/Pause</button>
                   <script>
function vid_play_pause() {
  var myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo");
  if (myVideo.paused) {
    myVideo.play();
  } else {
    myVideo.pause();
  }
}
                 </script>
```

That is my video player since they can't be able to scroll through the video ya,ya. Now I was thinking maybe I could add another button and then have the owner of the site say a password at the end of the video and make the page where they get their credits password encrypted.

My question is what is the best way about doing such a thing? I want it to be secure because I don't want him to lose money.

Answer (score 0):

What if you measure the time having video played and having it paused (assuming that there is no way to skip back and forth in the video)?

http://www.khanacademy.org uses similar approach for granting you points while watching training videos.